# Should I use nginx besides tomcat on single server instance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nginx, tomcat

I constructed my back-end server with Java + Spring boot, and deployed it with default WAS in it, tomcat.

Also, my service is very small, I think only 1 server instance would be reasonable for now.

But I wonder, in this case, is using nginx besides tomcat better choice?

I read some documents, and it seems like nginx is more fit when I have to load-balancing.

What is advantages of using nginx + tomcat over using only tomcat? Thanks.